# Should I test a minified production build with cypress?

Tags: testing, minify, cypress

I'm testing a meteor app (with React.js as client) with cypress.

I'm willing to create a CI/CD script which will execute my cypress tests, but I think I am missing a point; how will cypress test my app with a production version of my app running, meaning with minified code ?

I saw that best practices were to provide data-* attributes as selectors for my elements, but this is pointless if every value is going to be minified.

I believe this is the wrong approach since I didn't see any question here about that.. But maybe someone can help me understand why ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you sure these `data-*` attributes will be removed during the minimization? For me though, I'm not testing production code since I'm doing that intensive during the development :)

Comment: data-* are not striped on prod builds